# Unable to train rasa chatbot as it showing error with tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa-nlu, rasa

I'm trying to build a chatbot by considering rasa_nlu, followed the basic installation process of rasa from the main documentation. "rasa init" created the required folders and files for the processing of chatbot. I tried to train the model initially using rasa train command, but I got the below error of tensor flow. Kindly can someone let me know how can I overcome this error and move forward in developing chatbot.

Os :: MacOs bigsur M1

(Conda_Rasa) varun@Varuns-MacBook-Air Rasa_Chatbot % rasa train
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/bin/rasa", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/**main**.py", line 117, in main
cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/cli/train.py", line 59, in 
train_parser.set_defaults(func=lambda args: run_training(args, can_exit=True))
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/cli/train.py", line 91, in run_training
training_result = train_all(
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/api.py", line 106, in train
from rasa.model_training import train_async
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/model_training.py", line 22, in 
from rasa.nlu.model import Interpreter
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/nlu/model.py", line 14, in 
from rasa.nlu import components, utils
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/nlu/components.py", line 7, in 
import rasa.utils.train_utils
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/train_utils.py", line 37, in 
from rasa.utils.tensorflow.callback import RasaTrainingLogger, RasaModelCheckpoint
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/utils/tensorflow/callback.py", line 5, in 
import tensorflow as tf
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 41, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 39, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Users/varun/opt/anaconda3/envs/Conda_Rasa/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
(Conda_Rasa) varun@Varuns-MacBook-Air Rasa_Chatbot %

Comment: Welcome to SO, please use markdown tags to format your question.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with rasa, you installed tensorflow for the wrong architecture (arm or x86_64), this could happen if you install tensorflow for macos (which is for ARM architecture) inside a Rosetta terminal (which is x86_64 arch).

Comment: Rasa is not currently compatible with M1, as M1 requires mac optimised tensorflow, which is only available for version 2.4, and rasa requires tensorflow version 2.3